# Perl PDF::API2 displays boxes for plain ASCII letters

Tags: perl, pdf, pdf-generation, ascii

I'm trying to print some text as a simple PDF file. I used the following code, and I got a PDF file, but each letter shows as a box. For example five boxes shown for "Hello", and six boxes for "Hello1". I searched and found this kind of problem usually comes with UTF-8 characters, but mine uses just plain ASCII letters.

```
use PDF::API2;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new(); # create a blank pdf file            

my $page = $pdf->page(); # add a blank page                        
$page->mediabox('Letter'); # set page size

my $font = $pdf->corefont('Times'); # set up font

my $ttfPath = 'path/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf';
$font       = $pdf->ttfont($ttfPath);

my $text = $page->text(); # add text to page                                                                                                                          
$text->font($font, 20);
$text->translate(200, 700);

$text->text("Hello");

$pdf->saveas("test.pdf");
```

Comment: What kind of font is this? Possibly it doesn't have glyphs for the characters? Does it work if you use a different font? // In this case I think including a screenshot of the PDF is fair.

Comment: you're right. the ttf file does not have the font... thanks

Comment: If you want to mix little images and actual text, you'll need to have two different font objects I guess.

Comment: If your problem is solved then please write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such font as ***Times***. Use `Times-Roman`.

Comment: That might be an additional problem.